# 'package/after/glossaries' is deprecated in yathesis package

Tags: glossaries

I am currently using the yathesis package to write (thanks again for this great tool  ) but here I am still getting the following error message:
`Fichier : yathesis.cls Type : avertissement Message :Generic hook` 'package/after/glossaries' is deprecated.

I don't think this message is 'fatal' but I would like to understand...
I am using MacOS Ventura 13.1 and Texstudio 4.4.1.

I found in the class package this part of code:

```
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{glossaries}{%
    \RequirePackage{glossaries-babel}%
  }{%
  }%
}%
}%
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{glossaries}{%
    \IfLanguageName{english}{%
      \makeatletter
      \let\glossariescaptionsenglish\undefined
      \input{glossaries-english.ldf}
      \makeatother
    }{%
    }%
  }{%
  }%
}%
```

I'm at your disposal for more information,

Comment: hm, in part it is my fault. The hopatch package uses the old patch name. I will handle that, but probably yathesis should stop to use hopatch, so notify the author.